# Scatter plots, one column is Numerical i.e. speeds and other two columns are categorical

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three columns, one coulmn is titled as speed because it has speeds, other column is titled as PS and it has two categories "Available" and "Unavailable". Then it has another column called as CVLZs, it has three categories "Available CVLZ", "Occupied CVLZ" and "No CVLZ". I want to make 6 scatterplots, like Available CVLZ vs PC Available, Available CVLZ vs PC Unavailable but I also want to have speed as scatter plot.

I tried couple of codes but it didn't work and my spervisor asked me work on what should be on x axis to get two way distribution and something about continuous variables.

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and expected output. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. [Do not post images of code and/or data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6382434).